# How do I determine in which JSF version a tag was added?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, taglib, myfaces, tomahawk

I am in the process of upgrading an old web application from MyFaces 1.1 to version 2.2. I am new to JSF and still have a lot to learn about it (struggling a lot along the way). Because of this I often don't understand why a specific tag was used from some 3rd party tag library instead of the core JSF libraries.

For example, the application uses the `t:stylesheet` [tag](https://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_stylesheet.html) from the `Tomahawk` component library in the `head` of the page even though there seems to be a `h:outputStylesheet` [tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html) in the `html` library of JSF.

I was wondering if the `outputStylesheet` tag wasn't available in JSF 1.1 and was only added later or if there is another reason for choosing the Tomahawk tag over the JSF html tag.

Is there a way to determine which version of JSF added a specific tag to the core libraries? Apart from replacing the "2.1" in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html until I reach a the URL that isn't available?

Comment: There is not as far as I know (but I do not know all, not by a long shot). I doubt there is any reason to still use Tomahawk. If you do not want to make a full switch to JSF2.2 (e.g. not using facelets but keep using jsp), I would still suggest to try to remove Tomahawk from your project or at least as much as possible. The tomahawk site does not even reference 2.2 anymore (and 2.3 is also already released). Investigating what you ask is to cumbersome in my opinion and leads to sort of useless knowledge.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for your response. The tomahawk tag is just an example. I am now planning to make a complete switch to JSF2.2 and already wrote the first few Facelets that replace the existing JSPs. I'd still think that for upgrading projects it would be very useful to see with which version of JSF a specific tag was introduced. I was under the impression this would be stated in the JavaDoc pages themselves, but didn't find that information there yet.